# Change ListPreference style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-theme

I want to change default image of a `ListPreference` by creating a new `style`.

I did it with a `CheckBoxPreference` by inherit `Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox` and setting a new `android:button`, but I don't know how to do it on a `ListPreference`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an icon in the preference using the WidgetLayout property.

Example:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:dialogTitle="@string/mode_name"
    android:key="mode_name"
    android:order="0"
    android:summary=""
    android:title="@string/mode_name"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/mode_item_preference"
     />
```

And the mode_item_preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
```